# Find two points such that $f^2(a')=0$ and $f^2(b')=1$

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f : [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ surjective continuous map.
If $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=0$ with $0\leq a\leq b\leq 1$, then is possible to obtain two points $a'\leq b'$ such that $f^2(a')=0$ and $f^2(b')=1$ ?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: By $f^2$, do you mean $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$ or $f^2(x) = f(x)f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Joey Zou mentioned, I think OP means $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$. Thanks to IVT, since f is continuous with $f(b)=0,\ f(a)=1$, for $0 \leq b \leq 1$ there exists $a'\in (a,b)$ such that
$$
f(a')=b \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(f(a'))=f(b)=0
$$
Similarly, since $f(a')=b,\  f(b)=0$ and $b\geq a \geq 0$, there exists $b' \in (a',b)$ such that 
$$
f(b')=a \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(f(b'))=f(a)=1
$$
where $a'<b'$

Note: Surjectivity not used here.

Comment: Where are you getting the $f(1) = 0$ and $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: Oh sorry, let me fix it.